# Distinct Primes and Generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Review For Group Theory Final:

Let p and q be distinct primes.  How many generators does $\mathbb Z_{pq}$ have?

I know that $\mathbb Z_{pq}$  is a cyclic group and has at least one generator, $\langle 1\rangle$.  I know how to find the generators of $\mathbb Z_{pq}$ when dealing with modular addition.  I also think I know that if the element and $pq$ have a common divisor, then it can not be a generator.  But I am having issues visualizing this without know what $p$ and $q$ are.

Any help with this would be great! 
Thanks!

Comment: How many elements in your group, seen as integers, are coprime with $\;pq\;$ ? Or in other words, what is $\;\varphi(pq)\;$ ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to know what numbers, specifically, $p, q$ happen to be. You need only know that they are *distinct* and both *prime.* Since $p, q$ are distinct prime, $\gcd(p, q) = 1$, so indeed, $\mathbb Z_{pq}$ is cyclic.

Now, which elements (here, integers) are relatively prime to $pq$? 
Excluding the identity element, those will be your generators.

Recall that given they are prime, the number $pq$'s distinct prime decomposition is given by $p\cdot q$.

We need simply to exclude the identity (which generates only the trivial group), and we need to exclude elements $p$ and $q$, as they are the only divisors of $pq$ other than $1$, and $pq$, which is of course, the order of the group.

Comment: Why does $gcd(p,q)=1$ imply the group is cyclic?